# Periodic timer runs once, then errors

Tags: timer, nonetype, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

On a Raspberry Pi Pico v1.19.1, when I define my timer the first execution works fine. However subsequent periods fail with:

> 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object isn't callable

```
import machine, time
from machine import Timer


class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pulse = machine.Timer(-1)
        self.pulse.init(mode=Timer.PERIODIC, period=1000, callback=self.cb_pulse())

    def cb_pulse(self):
        print("whai!")

app()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the callback function themself, so without the **`()`**

```py
# Good 
self.pulse.init(mode=Timer.PERIODIC, period=200, callback=self.cb_pulse)
# Bad
self.pulse.init(mode=Timer.PERIODIC, period=200, callback=self.cb_pulse())
```

With the added `()`, you are actually passing the result/output of the callback method to the timer.
And as that returns nothing == `None`, so the timer tries to call 'None', which is indeed not a callable.

Working sample in simulator: https://wokwi.com/projects/354050429354521601

Comment: Jos, thank you! Your link aided in my understanding! In addition to that. My callback was lacking a parameter as evidenced by line 24 ```def cb_method(self, **t**):``` Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I can find that works with Micropython they can give me any timer function at all. But it works great for what I needed it for which is to make a one second tick counter. So that I could measure time inside of the WOKWI Online emulator.

```
jsjtick=1
def  tickjsj():
    global jsjtick
    jsjtick=jsjtick+1
machine.Timer().init(period=1000, callback=lambda t:tickjsj())

#redundantly display the time in the terminal
jsjtick2=0
while 1:
    if jsjtick!=jsjtick2
      print(" "*33,(13),end="","uptime=",jsjtick,chr,(13),end="")
      jsjtick!=jsjtick2
```

Comment: Please format Python code using PEP8 when answering, thanks!